# How can I put my tv audio to my computer with 3.5mm jack?

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi, tv, chromecast

Hello I have a chromecast and it is set up to my tv and my computer is connected to it and it sends the sound to my tv but I don't want that because I can't connect my headphones to it so I am trying to send the sound to my computer (laptop running windows 10) I go to the microphone place in my sound settings (3.5mm jack connected from my tv to my microphone jack in laptop) and it shows that it picks up sound (bar goes up and down to the sound) but I can't here anything in my headphones connected to my computer or even in the speakers... can someone please help me.

Here are the configuration tabs for my microphone:

[Advanced Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkccz.png)

[General Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7cj2.png)

[Levels Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEWIP.png)

[Listen Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTw8S.png)

Comment: You should try to explain the situation more clearly. You will not hear sound unless you enable monitoring on the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hear sound coming from the 3.5mm microphone jack via your speakers, you should enable listen mode.
[image: v]

But if you sending the sound from the same laptop, I would just set your output device to headphones, in this case you won't need to connect tv to laptop back.

Comment: I just enabled listen mode and I still can't hear the audio... is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Is "playback through" set to your headphones or default device?

Comment: yes I tried both headphones and default

Comment: Could you please upload screenshots of your configuration to the post?

Comment: Thanks. And what options do you have under "Playback through this device"?

Comment: I have: Default Playback Device, Headphones, Speakers, Headset. Under "Playback through this device"...

Comment: And you tried each of them followed by "Apply", "OK", correct?

Comment: yes I have tried them all

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately, I don't see anything that could prevent you from listening. May I also ask you to provide a screenshot of your available "Recording" devices?

Comment: OK thanks I will try messing around tomorrow to see if I can find anything that may allow me to hear sound.

Comment: You may also try this application: http://www.fox-magic.com/vac.php. I used it before to send sound in parallel to two different sound outputs. It's not free, unfortunately, as long as I remember.

Comment: Sooo... I have no idea what happened but I fixed it... No idea how but I fixed it... So once again thank you for your suggestions and help I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Very good to hear. My pleasure to help. :)